# Alternate solution for htaccess in ASP

Tags: .htaccess, asp-classic, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I have a shared hosting account and don't have access to IIS server, so can not install ISAPI_Rewrite on server or any other rewrite solution.

Website language is in classic ASP and want to create rewrite rule, but I cannot use .htaccess file.

So is there any alternate way or I can use .htaccess?

Thanks for help.

Comment: when did .htaccess ever have anything to do with asp? They're part of two different worlds.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting is Windows 2008 (IIS 7) then you can [install Helicon Ape onto your shared account](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/how-to-install-helicon-ape-on-shared-hosting/) for .htaccess support.

Comment: Thanks, but they have IIS6 server.

Answer (score 0):

If your hoster permits you to change the `404` custom error page in their control panel to an ASP script then there's a trick you can do that emulates a rewriting engine.

If you map your 404 custom error to a page such as `/404.asp` you can then parse the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. Here's a very simplistic skeleton you could start with:

```
<%
raw = Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")

' Extract URL
startPos = Instr(1, raw, ";",1) + 1
url = Mid(raw, startPos, Len(raw) - (startPos - 1))

' Assumes no wacky ports
startPos = Instr(1, url, ":80/",1)
If startPos = 0 Then 
  startPos = Instr(1, url, ":443/",1) + 4
Else
  startPos = startPos + 3
End If

' Get path/querystring
path = Mid(url, startPos, Len(url) - (startPos - 1))

' Now parse your path/querystring...your code goes here

Server.Transfer somePage
%>
```